# How to render String of functional component in React?

Tags: javascript, database, reactjs, case, render

I have use case to render component from database. In data base they are stored as string format like below:

```
let Sample = `({firstName})=><h1>My name is {firstName}</h1>`;
```

When I try to render this in react, it shows as string. How to render string type of functional component.

```
class App extends Component {

  this.state = {
  "sathish" : "firstName",
  }

  render (){
      // how do it use string of functional component like below
      return <Sample firstName={this.state.firstName} />
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this approach. Why would you want to do it

Comment: are you aware `Sample` is a string ?

Comment: Remove backticks

Comment: yes i aware but they stored as string.. i want this string to convert functional component... how do i do it?

Answer (score -1):

you can use eval for this:
let Sample = eval(`({firstName})=><h1>My name is {firstName}</h1>`);

or more complicate solution it's https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser#example

Comment: That's not what he's looking for

Comment: OP said they stored these component strings in the database.